# Spring cloud contracts with generic api

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-contract, contract

How to use spring cloud contracts with generic api. I'm asking about REST contracts on producer service. So consider an example. I have a service which allows to store user data into different formats into database and acts like proxy between service and database. It has parameters required for all consumers, and parameters which depend on a consumer.

```
class Request<T> {
    Long requestId;
    String documentName;
    T documentContent;
}
```

And it has two consumers.

Consumer 1:

```
{
  "requestId": 1,
  "documentName": "login-events",
  "documentContent": {
    "userId": 2,
    "sessionId": 3
  }
}
```

Consumer 2:

```
{
  "requestId": 1,
  "documentName": "user-details",
  "documentContent": {
    "userId": 2,
    "name": "Levi Strauss",
    "age": 11
  }
}
```

As you can see `documentContent` depends on consumer. In I want to write such contracts, which will check content of this field on consumer side and ignore it on producer side. Options like

```
"documentContent": ["age": $(consumer(11))] //will produce .field(['age']").isEqualTo(11)
```

and

```
"documentContent": ["age": $(consumer(11), producer(optional(anInteger())))] //will require field presence
```

didn't work. Of course I may write `"documentContent": []` or even ignore this field in contracts, but I want them to act like Rest Api documentation. Does anybody has ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ignore the optional element and define 2 contracts. One with the `age` value and one without it. The one with the `age` value should contain also contain a `priority` field. You can read about priority here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/project-features.html#contract-dsl-http-top-level-elements

It would look more or less like this (contract in YAML):

```
priority: 5 # lower value of priority == higher priority
request:
  ...
  body:
     documentContent:
         age: 11
response:
  ...
```

and then the less concrete case (in YAML)

```
priority: 50 # higher value of priority == lower priority
request:
  ...
  body:
     documentContent:
         # no age
response:
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, that is more applicable for my case (groovy code):

```
def documentContent = [
  "userId": 2,
  "sessionId": 3
]
Contract.make {
  response {
    body(
      [
      ............
      "documentContent" : $(consumer(documentContent), producer(~/.+/)),
      ............
      ]
    )
  }
}
```

But please, take into consideration, that I stubbed `documentContent` value with a `String` ("documentContent") in producer contract test.